# How can I hide the navigation bar BEFORE the first page has displayed?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am building a `Xamarin Android` app using `Xamarin.Forms` my `App` class is really simple and contains one page like so:

```
public App()
{
    // The root page of your application
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new ContentPage()
    {
        Title = "My First Page!",
        Content = new Label()
        {
            Text = "Test Page!",
            TextColor = Color.White,
            FontSize = 25,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
        }
    });
}
```

and my `MainActivity` class like so:

```
[Activity(Label = "GridTest", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```

When I launch the application though the `NavigationBar` is displayed with the word **"GridTest"** displayed in the top left which looks rubbish, shown below:

**This is the NavigationBar I would like to hide.**

[image]

After this my application loads with the navigation bar fine. Shown below:

**I would like to keep this Navigation Bar**

[image]

So my question is. How do I hide the Android `NavigationBar` that is displayed **BEFORE** the initial page has loaded?

**SIDE NOTE:**

I have tried `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(page,false);` but this does not work. This hides the `NavigationBar` for the first page shown below.
[image]

which I would like to keep! This also does not hide the **"GridTest"** navigation bar I am looking to hide (shown in screenshot 1)

To reiterate... I am looking to hide the **INITIAL** navigation bar. provided by the Android `MainActivity` **NOT** the `Xamarin.Forms` navigation bar

Comment: Add `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` to you theme in your activity. The Xamarin forms application takes some time to load and till then it shows your main activity. So you need to change your main activity. What people do in order to remove this they add a Splash screen to look good.

Comment: @AkashAmin Have you got an example of how to add the theme to my `MainActivity`?

Comment: Posted my ans below. @user1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main activity which will load the first time the application starts.

```
[Activity(Label = "testapp", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/MyTheme", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public class SplashActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
           // SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LaunchScreen); //Set a splash screen here if you wish
            Java.Lang.Runnable runnable = new Java.Lang.Runnable(() =>
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
                StartActivity(i);
            });

            new Handler().PostDelayed(runnable, 1000);
        }
    }
```

The theme for that activity must be saved to `Resources/drawable/styles.xml` and is

```
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

This `SplashActivity` will load and call `MainActivity`

and your `MainActivity` will look like this:

```
[Activity(Label = "GridTest", Icon = "@drawable/icon", ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```

You dont need to set the Theme here and it will work as before. Another **Important** note about the `MainActivity` is you **MUST** remove `MainLauncher = true`

Comment: Have you got this working for a `Xamarin.Forms` application? I have copied the code to the folder `Resources/Values/Styles.xml` and also had to wrap the `Style` in a `Resources` tag but When I run the application I get Object Reference not set in the Main Activity

Comment: Yes I have this working. Which android version are you using..? and on what the object reference is not set?

Comment: Does this code remove the `ActionBar` for the whole application? Meaning if I set this as my theme can I still use the ActionBar when my Xamarin.Forms application loads?

Comment: Yes..It will remove the actionbar only from the activity. And in xaml when you load a navigation page it will come back.

Comment: The null reference is being thrown at `at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.UpdateActionBarBackgroundColor ()` so its on the Xamarin.Forms side. I am using Xamarin.Forms V2.3.0.46-pre2. and target platform is Android 6.0. Is this working with the sample code from the question?

Comment: Okay so here is the thing. The problem is with the `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>` if you set it to true then that exception will not occur but might throw another exception. So what have I done is created another activity which will show the initial page and then after 1 or 2 seconds im calling the activity which will load my xamarin forms application. Its a lenghty process though. If you want I can paste the code.@user1

Comment: If you could update the answer with the code I will give it a try. I am pretty good with `Xamarin.Forms` and creating a Android new activity

Comment: Thanks that works. I have edited the answer and bulked it out with a bit more info. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to hide that navigation bar by setting a simple attribute in your page like so:
`<ContentPage NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"
    ..... >
</ContentPage>`

Comment: This hides the `NavigationBar` for the initial Page that is displayed. I am specifically talking about the bar that appears before this page is displayed. I would like to keep the FirstPage's navigation bar

Comment: you please try it and then see it will working defiantly. i am already check it and it is worked very well.

Comment: I have tried it and this does not work. This hide the `NavigationBar` for the first page. Which I would like to keep. It does not hide the "GridTest" navigationbar. see question for reiteration

Comment: While this may not answer this question, it did solve my problem - that being, when my app started, the navigation bar was visible for a split second before disappearing.  I was calling NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(p, false); in my page's OnAppearing, but moving it to the page XAML caused the nav bar to be hidden before the page was shown, which is what I wanted.